# How to select from table MariDB

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I need to get value from specific data in my_table in MariaDB and store it into variables @var1 and @var2.
In SQL Server I use :

```
Select @var1=field1 ,@var2=field2 from my_table where id=@varid...
```

What is the correct syntax for MariaDB or My SQL?

Comment: "I want to get value @var1" - what does that mean?

Comment: I'msorry... I've Edit my questions..

Comment: "@var1" and "@var2" these are variables or what can you clarify about this part

Comment: yes.. @var1 and Var2 are variables , I want to use these 2 var for next process,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equal sign compares left and right value and returns 1 (true)/0 (false) or NULL if one of the values is NULL.

To assign a value to a variable use `:=`:

```
SELECT @var1:=field1 ,@var2:=field2 from my_table where id=@varid
```